# Show that there is not set which has the set $\mathbb{Q}$ as its set of accumulation points.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is not set which has the set $\mathbb{Q}$ as its set of accumulation points.

My guess: If $E$ is a set that has $\mathbb{Q}$ as its set of accumulation points then that would mean that for any $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\delta>0$ we have at least one $e\in E$ such that $e\in (q-\delta,q+\delta).$ I don't know how to carry on further. Any advice/hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try proving that if the set of accumulation points contains all the rationals, then it must also contain all real numbers.

Comment: I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and so there will always be an irrational number between two distinct rational numbers.

Comment: Or I could argue by saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ must be closed and so it must contain all its limit points.

Comment: That's a good direction to go. I'm not sure how much of topology you have available to you, but you are very close to done with this proof.

Comment: @G.Snapsmath can I say that $q_n-(1/n)<p<q_n+(1/n)$ where $q_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers and $p$ is an irrational number? Then we have a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ and so $p$ must be in $\mathbb{Q}$ as well since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed.

Comment: You want to be careful about how you define q_n. You want to construct the sequence by taking the 1/n neighborhoods of your point p. Then take q_n to be a rational in there by the density of the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mathbb Q$ is part of the set of accumulation points of some set $S$. Then, for every $r \in \mathbb Q , \epsilon > 0$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $|s - r |< \epsilon$.

Now, we can show that every real number is a limit point. To do this, if $p \in \mathbb R$, find a rational $q$ such that $|p-q| < \frac \epsilon 2$, and then since $q$ is a limit point, find $s \in S$ so that $|s - q| < \frac \epsilon 2$. By the triangle inequality, we get $|s-p| < \epsilon$. This shows that $p$ is also a limit point of $S$.

It follows that the set of limit points of $S$ must be the whole of $\mathbb R$, if it were to contain $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Could you please see my comment above....

Comment: Yes, I think the comment is correct.